# Hover effect or tooltip on recharts reference line

Tags: javascript, typescript, reference, recharts

Looking to add a custom tooltip that displays on hover of a reference line. But it looks like there is no built in capability for this :(.
Has anyone found a hacky solution for this?

Tried adding a onMouseHover on reference line, grabbing the coords/position in the custom tooltip element and using the onMouseHover on the actual linechart. None of these seemed to work :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I got your question right, I might have had the same issue.
The line that is displayed when the tooltip is shown is done with the **cursor** prop.

Please refer to this example [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/recharts-basic-line-chart-with-different-colors-dynamic-gradients-forked-yygwmb?file=/index.js)